# Safely add GitHub personal access token to code in the hub

Tags: android, security, github

I have a code to submit as an assignment through GitHub. It is an Android app that involves making an authorised query to github API. I have generated a personal access token for the authorisation. This token, or the token in another form, has to be in the code. Is there a safe way of adding this token so that someone with the link to the repo may not see the token explicitly?

The repo is public. I'm not looking at any other form of  authorization because the assignment requires use of personal access tokens.

I have even tried to push a 'naked' valid token (though with a limited scope) to the repo but github revoked it automatically.

Pls what can I do about this?

Comment: You should have a configuration file where the token is stored but not committed to the repo. Anyone who wants to checkout your project has to use his own access token.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the only option I have..